# TFS Web Interface

Tags: tfs

We are currently trying to find a new bug tracking and integration software and we were looking at FogBugz, Jira and TFS. My question is about TFS.

I have done some research and found that TFS has "Power Tools" in which Non IT users can log on and get some information, but all the examples and tools I have found didnt really give them the kind of UI that other bug tracking software provides such as estimates, full fledged reporting on hours, P&L, Bugs Released, When A feature will be complete. For example Fogbugz has a feature that will predict when a feature will go live off past estimates, is there any way to get that kind of functionality from TFS? Or Any of the functionality listed above in a web interface?

Answer (score 4):

Team Web Access is built into TFS 2010 ([grab a trial](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=3660cacf-f077-44d3-a9d9-97e801da2035&displaylang=en) and try)

[Urban Turtle](http://www.UrbanTurtle.com) is the best Web UI for dealing with Work Items in TFS.

Reporting and Bug reports are available, though everyone, everywhere wants something different.

P&L reports are not available out of the box.

There are minimal prediction reports, but it's all BS anyways :).  Burndown reports give you information about your likelihood to delivery.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention, there is a tool called [Team System Web Access Power Tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980951) with following features:

```
   * Direct links to work items, query results, diffs, change sets and more
   * Display custom controls on work item forms
   * View queued builds new, queue new builds
   * Add new work items or edit existing ones
   * Work with any type of work item, including custom ones
   * Add new work item queries or edit existing ones
   * View, download, upload, check-in and check-out documents on SharePoint team portal
   * View reports, export as PDF or Excel
   * Browse source control repositories, download files, view changesets, diffs, histories, and annotated views
   * View build results, start or stop builds
   * Search for keywords in work items
```

If you need more than that you'll have to [integrate](http://geekswithblogs.net/hinshelm/archive/2010/05/03/integrate-sharepoint-2010-with-team-foundation-server-2010.aspx) the TFS with SharePoint server which will give you all you asked for in your question and much more...

Comment: I'm not aware of any way (out of the box) to do hours, P&L, or evidence based scheduling as asked.  If you know of a way to do those things a link would be helpful.